# Does Django Debug Toolbar work with DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to setup [Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to debug some API methods via DRF's Browsable API. I've went through the steps described on the [Installation](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) page (like updating `INSTALLED_APPS`, `MIDDLEWARE`, etc.) but still can't see any toolbar. So does Debug Toolbar work with DRF? How to debug the issue with it not showing up?

Comment: I also found a way to use it with DRF AJAX requests by using https://github.com/djsutho/django-debug-toolbar-request-history which will store all recent requests so that can be accessed later from the Debug Toolbar interface. You can use your app, make requests, then go view the profiles! The Debug Toolbar project is integrating this directly into the project soon: https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/pull/1250

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it works fine if you have the correct `INTERNAL_IPS = [..]` . With docker you also have to find out the IP of serving proxy-server for example `nginx`-container.

Answer (score 30):

Didn't work for me until I've added

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": lambda request: True,
}
```

Comment: Just note that this will bypass the INTERNAL_IPS & DEBUG checks - https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#show-toolbar-callback

Comment: It's not recommended, because it will show the debug tool in production mode. by default, it will be shown only when debug is true

Comment: Adding this answer without an explanation about what it does / implies is very dangerous.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, *Debug Toolbar* works with DRF, but you need also to add `INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1',]` to your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Make sure you put the right ip-address to `INTERNAL_IPS`  if you use a reverse proxy.